# Can I combine two pm break mount adapter?

Tags: brakes, shimano, disc-brake

I think about upgrade my shimano rear brake disc from 180 to 203 mm. The mount system is a pm 160 direct, meaning I currently already have a pm 180mm adapter.
Weirdly, I couldn't find an adapter for `pm 160 direct` > `pm 203`. According a few tables aparently the `SM-MA-R203` should do the job, but on every store it's written that this adapter is only for 180 direct mounts, which confuses me.

Would it be also possible to combine my existing `pm 180` adapter and the `SM-MA-R203` one? Or which adapted would be the correct for a `pm 160 direct` > `pm 203`?

Comment: Chainreactioncycles.com list a Hope PM 160 to 203 front and rear. it's listed as Hope Mount Type C. presumably other brands are available. and your LBS can probably source any number of adapters